# I tried to load the Location of the player and the player into the database when breaking the block, but it outputs an error

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

EventBlock

```
package minecord.plugingenerin.Event;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockBreakEvent;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitScheduler;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitTask;

import javax.management.timer.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class EventBlock implements Listener {


    @EventHandler
    public void onDestroy(BlockBreakEvent blockBreak) throws SQLException {
        Player player = blockBreak.getPlayer(); //Получение игрока
        Block block = blockBreak.getBlock();
        Location loc = block.getLocation();
        World world = block.getWorld();
        Material material = block.getType();
        player.sendMessage("Блок сломан");
        SqliteDB db =new SqliteDB();
        db.insert(loc,player);


    }
}
```

SqliteDB

```
package minecord.plugingenerin.Event;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SqliteDB {
    SqliteDB program = new SqliteDB();
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:memory:F:/Location.db");
    Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
    void insert(Location location, Player user) throws SQLException {
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert LocatioInfo values('"+location+"','"+user+"')");
        stmt.executeUpdate("backup to C:Users/Татьяна/Desktop/Server 1.20.1 paper/plugins/DB/backup.db");
    }

    public SqliteDB() throws SQLException {
        stmt.executeUpdate("create table Location(Location Location, User TEXT)");

    }
}
```

error

> [16:56:39 ERROR]: Could not pass event BlockBreakEvent to PluginGenerin v1.0
> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
> at minecord.plugingenerin.Event.SqliteDB.(SqliteDB.java:12) ~[original-PluginGenerin-1.0.jar:?]
> at minecord.plugingenerin.Event.SqliteDB.(SqliteDB.java:12) ~[original-PluginGenerin-1.0.jar:?]
> at minecord.plugingenerin.Event.SqliteDB.(SqliteDB.java:12) ~[original-PluginGenerin-1.0.jar:?]
> at minecord.plugingenerin.Event.SqliteDB.(SqliteDB.java:12) ~[original-PluginGenerin-1.0.jar:?]
> at minecord.plugingenerin.Event.SqliteDB.(SqliteDB.java:12) ~[original-PluginGenerin-1.0.jar:?]
> at minecord.plugingenerin.Event.SqliteDB.(SqliteDB.java:12) ~[original-PluginGenerin-1.0.jar:?]

I tried deleting

```
SqliteDB db =new SqliteDB();
db.insert(loc,player);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by this statement:

```java
public class SqliteDB {
    SqliteDB program = new SqliteDB();
    ...
}
```

While the class SqliteDB gets instantiated, the field `program` is created and assigned to a new SqliteDB class, which has a field `program` which gets created and assigned to a new SqliteDB class, and so on until a stack overflow occurs.